# Trigger.IO can't install on iOS 8.1

Tags: trigger.io, ios8.1

I believe there is a problem between trigger.io and ios version 8.1. One of our testing devices updated to 8.1 and we're getting install service failed message when running normally and serving.

> [INFO] ERROR: Start installation service failed!
>
> [ERROR] Failed when running C:\Users\foo\forge-workspace\bar.lib\win-ios-install.exe:
> Installing c:\users\foo\appdata\local\temp\tmpstpb68 to:
> 9a47dec7bb03aa5ad61381a1722385c0e44890dd
> ERROR: Start installation service failed!

Anyone else having the same issue? is there any other reason why we might get this error message?

Answer (score 1):

Apple have made changes to the iOS8 installation service which breaks the 3rd party libraries we rely on for device installation under Windows.

We're currently working on a solution with the library authors.

A workaround you can use in the meantime is to package your app and then use iTunes to install the .ipa on your device.

Comment: We're still experiencing the problem... after 2 months, this should already be resolved.

Comment: It's frustrating, maybe add your voice to: https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/issues/117